# Smooth Text On Glass

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, aero

I have seen many other samples out there that draw smooth text on glass. But I can't use them. I need every single label that gets added at runtime to be smooth. I can't just "draw" text onto the screen.

Is this at all possible, and are there and sources around?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a long at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx#S6

It's a bit long but it answers alot of your question and alore more in regards to glass.

but the relevant part for you directly is

> One particular gotcha is that
>   rendering a GDI item in black uses the
>   bit pattern 0x00000000-which also
>   happens to be a completely transparent
>   black if you are using an alpha
>   channel. This means that if you draw
>   with a black GDI brush or pen you'll
>   get a transparent color, not a black
>   one. The biggest problem this presents
>   is when you try to use the default
>   text color in a control of a text
>   label that sits on the glass area.
>   Since the default text color is
>   usually black, the DWM will consider
>   this to be transparent and the text
>   will be written in the glass
>   incorrectly. An example can be seen in
>   Figure 10. The first line is written
>   with GDI+, the second is a text label
>   control using the default color. As
>   you can see, it's nearly illegible
>   because it's actually incorrectly
>   rendered text that shows up as gray,
>   not black.
>
> Happily, there are a number of ways
>   around this problem. Using owner-draw
>   controls is one. Rendering to a bitmap
>   that has an alpha channel is another.
>   Fortunately, the easiest way to get
>   text on controls is to let the .NET
>   Framework 2.0 use GDI+ for you. This
>   is easily accomplished by setting the
>   UseCompatibleTextRendering property on
>   your controls. By default, this
>   property is set to false so that
>   controls written for previous versions
>   of the .NET Framework will render the
>   same. But if you set it to true, your
>   text will come out looking correct.
>   You can set the property globally with
>   the
>   Application.SetUseCompatibleTextRenderingDefault
>   method.

He also provides example code you can place in your Main()

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
    Application.Run(new GlassForm());
}
```

But I recommend reading the article, It'll clear up alot of what's going on with Aero/Glass

Cheers,
Phyx

Comment: Thank you, Phyx. that was the article that I originally read, everal times. Setting the Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true); to true makes no noticable difference on my machine.

Comment: A slightly more work variant then: You could try creating a custom label that extends the normal Label. overriding the OnPaint event and using DrawThemeTextEx instead.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298819/using-drawthemetextex-in-c/2781072#2781072

Comment: Thank you Phyx, looking at it now.